# What's the role of the と particle in this sentence?

Tags: particles

ずっと前から東南アジアを旅する**と**言っている。

I'm sorry if this is badly formatted, this is my first question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, と is being used in its quotation form, meaning that whatever is before the と for this example is a quotation. The clue here is the end of the sentence. If we consider only what's after the と for a second:

~と言っている = "...is saying"

So, then we have to answer who is saying what (from context or stated) and what is being said. Here, what's between our は or が particles and the と particle is the section that is being quoted. Since we don't have a topic or subject in this sentence, the implied context is that you're probably the one who is saying this. Consider looking at this sentence like this:

「ずっと前から東南アジアを旅する」と言っている。

I'm saying that "I travel to Southeast Asia since long ago".

Comment: It would be more like ずっと前から「東南アジアを旅する」と言っている with ずっと前から modifying 言っている rather than 旅する.